# Show one div and hide others on clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with 37 links and 37 hidden divs with some text. The counter starts with 3 and ends with 40. What I would like to do is to display a div when I click a link and also hide all the other divs.

Links look like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="week_3">Week 3</a>
<a href="#" rel="week_4">Week 4</a>
```

Divs look like this:

```
<div id="week_3" style="display: none">[...]</div>
<div id="week_4" style="display: none">[...]</div>
```

I would like to perform this task using jQuery. What I don't know how to do is make a loop and check if any of those links have been clicked.

Comment: Would it be one div showing at a time? Or if the user clicks three links do you want the corresponding 3 divs to be shown but all others remain hidden?

Comment: One div at a time. The user clicks on link with rel="week_3" and div with id="week_3" gets displayed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something along the line of :

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   var target = $(this).attr('rel');
   $("#"+target).show().siblings("div").hide();
});
```

Should do the trick.

P.S: your divs have to be in a container for this to work.
[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VpkKn/)

Comment: I used this but I added inheritance for extra safety that no other links on that page would get affected. In my case `project-note-box li a`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 3</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 4</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 5</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 6</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 7</a>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
    <div id="content6">This is the test content for part 6</div>
    <div id="content7">This is the test content for part 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Script:

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n53qg/)

Answer (score 3):

you can check below both `jsfiddle` file. it's working fine. do you want like this type?

http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/ [ Accordion Type ]

http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/6/ [ Tab Type ]

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "a" ).each(function( index ) {
  var id = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('.data').hide();
  $('#'+id).show();
});
```

Comment: was just about to post something similar. This is how I'd go about it. Here's the fiddle i was working on: http://jsfiddle.net/KNrNj/ but the above is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing

Give your divs a class
so that when you click on a links you can hide that particular class and then showing the desired div by click of link

```
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>

<a href="#" onClick="$('.abc').hide();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some common class for all `div`s say like `class='week'`. And use following to do the required :

```
$("a[rel^='week']").on('click', function(){
  $("div.week").hide();
  var targetDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
  $("#"+targetDiv).show();
```

});