# What is the use for the off method inside this jQuery hide and show code?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I'm using the code from this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055789/3250077 for a project.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/ on line 12 there is a `off` method

```
faqTab.off('click').on('click', function()
```

I'm new to programming and I read that it removes event handlers, but when I delete that part of the code, like this

```
faqTab.on('click', function()
```

nothing appears to change. What is happening inside the code? Is this really necesary or is just a "good practice". Not using this can lead to problems in more complex code?

Comment: Event handlers will stack up, so if you keep adding a click handler then it will fire multiple times.  By removing and click handlers you ensure that this won't happen.  I'd personally say it's bad coding though.  There are much better ways to make sure it doesn't happen.

Comment: In that particular case, the .off makes absolutely no sense unless the code is being included multiple times (which is a bad idea anyway) it's rare to ever need to use .off().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't remove an event handler before you add a new handler you can end up with the same method being called multiple times for the same event. So the answer to whether or not this makes a difference really depends on how often this code is run. As a general rule it isn't a bad practice to remove the existing handlers before adding a new handler.

Take the following example. In this example you would have an issue if this click function was called either directly or indirectly from the button being clicked:

```
var clickFunction = function () {
    // add the event AGAIN: BAD!
    $("#test-button").on("click", clickFunction);
};
```

**See this in a JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Qv8T/1/

Comment: This is an excellent answer. The JSFiddle really makes it very clear. Thanks a lot!