# How to show and hide a section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I want to show the div of selected HTML link.

**For example:**

I clicked on the html link *Categories* the `<div id="categories" ... >` will be showed and the other div's will hide.

**HTML**

```
<div id="col-navigation">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Quizzes </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Categories </a>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a href="#"> Jump </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div id="quizzes"> //default showed
     Quizzes!
</div>

<div id="categories" style="display:none">
     Categories!
</div>

 <div id="jump" style="display:none">
     Jump!
</div>
```

Comment: so what have your tried, anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show one div and hide others on clicking a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055524/show-one-div-and-hide-others-on-clicking-a-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$('#col-navigation a').click(function(){
   $('#quizzes,#categories,#jump').hide();
   $('#' + $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase()).show();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/0hpz1p1n/)

OR

```
$('#col-navigation a').click(function(){
   $('#quizzes,#categories,#jump').show()
   .not('#' + $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase()).hide();
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KartikeyaKhosla/0hpz1p1n/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#col-navigation a").click(function(e) {
   var getText = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
   $("#"+getText).toggle().siblings().hide();
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

use the above code to make it work.

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/z4bprass/1/

Comment: Please review my question. I want to show only the clicked html link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` `:target`, general siblings selector `~`

```css
:target {
  display: block !important;
}
:target ~ div[id] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="col-navigation">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#quizzes"> Quizzes </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#categories"> Categories </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#jump"> Jump </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <div id="categories" style="display:none">
    Categories!
  </div>

  <div id="jump" style="display:none">
    Jump!
  </div>

  <div id="quizzes">//default showed Quizzes!
  </div>
</div>
```