# JavaScript toggle - show some, and remove some text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show text when one of the elements are 'clicked', but hide the others.

So when I press 'Home' the other elements are on 'hide' and, at the same time, change the active class.

Please help.

```js
function toggle(obj) {
  var obj = document.getElementById(obj);
  if (obj.style.display == "block") obj.style.display = "none";
  else obj.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="toggle('Home')">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="toggle('Project')">Project</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="toggle('Contact')">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="informasjon" id="Home" style="display:none;">
  bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="informasjon1" id="Contact" style="display:none;">

  <br>
  <a href="mailto:blablabla@gmail.com">blabla</a>
</div>
<div class="informasjon1" id="Project" style="display:none;">
  Different bla bla bla


</div>
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: Yes it is - how to make the script hide the other text when one is showing. And how to make one of them active when each is pressed.

Comment: Already posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055524/show-one-div-and-hide-others-on-clicking-a-link/18055622 solution with 3 lines of code.

Comment: Salazar, that "how" is not in your OP, and there is no questions mark anywhere. Just saying: you could update the OP and turn it into a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all the elements on each click, then show the clicked one. Also, I will suggest you to avoid inline event handler by using `addEventListener`. You can use *data-* attribute to keep the reference of the id of the respective element.

**Demo:**

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="Home">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="Project">Project</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="Contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="informasjon" id="Home">
  bla bla bla
</div>
<div class="informasjon" id="Contact" style="display:none;">
  <br>
  <a href="mailto:blablabla@gmail.com">blabla</a>
</div>
<div class="informasjon" id="Project" style="display:none;">
  Different bla bla bla
</div>
<script>
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('#navbar a');
  links.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', toggle)
  })
  function toggle() {
    links.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    this.classList.add('active');
    var dataEl = document.querySelectorAll('.informasjon');
    dataEl.forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
    var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    obj.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and therefore arguably the best, solution would be to avoid using JavaScript for the most part, and use CSS.

I've made some changes to your HTML – removing the JavaScript from your `<a>` elements, replacing the `<div id="navbar">` with a semantic `<nav>` element, and placing the `<a>` elements within an `<ol>`, also I've added a class to your 'content' elements because I couldn't decide if the `<div id="Home">` element was meant to have the class of `informasjon` or if it was a typo given the remaining elements were of class `informasjon1` – so the approach below takes advantage of the CSS `:target` pseudo-class to style the element that is targetted by the fragment-identifier in the URL, the part following the `#` character:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Roboto, Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

div.content-unit {
  display: none;
}

div.content-unit:target {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Project">Project</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<div class="informasjon content-unit" id="Home">
  This is in the 'home' area
</div>
<div class="informasjon1 content-unit" id="Contact">
  This is in the 'contact' area
  <a href="mailto:blablabla@gmail.com">blabla</a>
</div>
<div class="informasjon1 content-unit" id="Project">
  This is in the 'project' area
</div>
```

As CSS works with the majority of the functionality, there are a couple aspects that require JavaScript; on page-load we need to show the correct 'content' to match the 'active' button on page-load (assuming that a hash isn't reliably set on page-load), and we need to add the 'active' class to the correct `<a>` when the links are followed.

First, a simple JavaScript function to show the 'active' `<a>` element:

```js
// defining a named function, using Arrow syntax, passing in the
// Event Object from the (later) use of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const showActive = (e) => {
  // here we're searching the <nav> element to find all elements
  // with the class of 'active', and then iterating over that
  // NodeList with NodeList.prototype.forEach():
  document.querySelectorAll('nav .active').forEach(
    // here we again use Arrow syntax, and pass in a
    // reference to the current element of the NodeList;
    // we then use the classList API to remove the 'active'
    // class from the element's class-list:
    (activeElem) => activeElem.classList.remove('active')
  )
  // we're binding the event-handler (this function) to the <a>
  // elements, but an <a> element can have descendant elements,
  // so here we find the EventObject.currentTarget which is the
  // element to which the event-listener was bound (the <a>)
  // and we again use the classList API to add the 'active' class:
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
}

// here we use document.querySelectorAll() to find all <a> elements
// within the <nav> element, and then use NodeList.prototype.forEach()
// to iterate over that NodeList:
document.querySelectorAll('nav a').forEach(
  // here we again use an Arrow function, to bind the showActive()
  // function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the
  // event-handler for the 'click' event:
  (aElem) => aElem.addEventListener('click', showActive)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Ubuntu, Roboto, Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li a {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

div.content-unit {
  display: none;
}

div.content-unit:target {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  background: palegreen;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="#Home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Project">Project</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>

<div class="informasjon content-unit" id="Home">
  This is in the 'home' area
</div>
<div class="informasjon1 content-unit" id="Contact">
  This is in the 'contact' area
  <a href="mailto:blablabla@gmail.com">blabla</a>
</div>
<div class="informasjon1 content-unit" id="Project">
  This is in the 'project' area
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the class of Home for this to work, but hopefully it helps you in case this isn't exactly what you need.

```js
    function toggle(obj) {
        let arrClass = document.getElementsByClassName("informasjon1");
        let object=document.getElementById(obj);
        let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

        for (let i = 0; i < navbar.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if(navbar.childNodes[i].innerHTML == obj)   navbar.childNodes[i].className = "active";
            else navbar.childNodes[i].className = "inactive";
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < arrClass.length; i++) {
            if (arrClass[i].id == object.id)    arrClass[i].style.display = "block";
            else    arrClass[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="toggle('Home')">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"onClick="toggle('Project')">Project</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="toggle('Contact')">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div class="informasjon1" id="Home" style="display:none;">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
    <div class="informasjon1" id="Contact" style="display:none;"><br>
        <a href="mailto:blablabla@gmail.com">blabla</a>
    </div>
    <div class="informasjon1" id="Project" style="display:none;">
        Different bla bla bla
    </div>
```